# How can I reinstall Windows 8 on my Acer Aspire V, which lacks a CD/DVD drive?

Tags: windows-8

So i have an Acer Aspire V that came with Windows 8.
A couple of weeks after i got the computer i installed Ubuntu on dual boot with windows 8 ND at a certain point i did a full install of Ubuntu.
But now i want to reinstall windows 8 on it , preferably a legit version, but i have no disk tray on my laptop, i tried creating bootable usb stick with pirate copies of windows 8 and it never boot from the usb, and secure boot is disable.
Is there any way i could make it work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's what happens when you use pirated/cracked softwares.

I would recommend you to either use a legitimate Windows copy or try another free Linux distribution like Mint or Fedora.

And as far as bootable usb goes, there's probably something wrong with your pirated Windows or you've failed to create a bootable usb drive.

Anyway, first make sure that you've a working Windows copy and then use [Unetbootin](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unetbootin/) in Ubuntu to create a bootable usb drive.

Comment: I tried with a non official Microsoft Windows 8 version and burned the USB with unetbootin but when I reboot it say that I miss the windows BCD to boot. If I get a legit copy of windows 8 to download from Microsoft and burn it do you think that the same thing would happen?

Comment: I think it's a partition issue caused by dual boot. Even a legit copy might not solve it. Can you do a clean install?

Comment: I can't, my laptop doesn't have a disk tray so I can't do a clean disk install.

Comment: By clean disk I meant formatting the hard drive completely.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows 8 was factory-installed, then it should have a recovery option in the boot menu to allow you to reset the disc to the factory-installed state, unless you deleted the recovery partitions.

This will remove every file you have put on the system, so make sure you have backed up all the files you need before you do this.

Comment: I'm not sure but think that I erased the recovery partition.At the moment I can just boot from my USB stick with windows 8 on it. But when I boot there's an error about something in windows to boot , the BCD as far as I remember. At the moment I'm not even able to boot in Ubuntu.

Comment: In that case, you'll need an installation disc on an external drive, but I don't know if this can reinstate your original licence. You should probably see if Acer can supply one; otherwise, you may have to purchase a new licence (or stick with Ubuntu, as I do).